# Remove HighChart Rendered Button

Tags: svg, highcharts

I am using the `chart.renderer` to add a button via:

```
    normalState = new Object();
    normalState.stroke_width = null;
    normalState.stroke = null;
    normalState.fill = null;
    normalState.padding = null;
    normalState.r = 3;

    hoverState = new Object();
    hoverState = normalState;
    hoverState.fill = 'red';

    pressedState = new Object();
    pressedState = normalState;
    custombutton = chart.renderer.button('Reset Chart', 74, 10, function () {
        chartMainsetChartInit(chartSeries);
    }, null, hoverState, pressedState).add();
```

This does show the button and it does fire the function I need. However, I am unable to remove this button. I have tried:

```
chart.renderer.button(custombutton).destroy();
```

And

```
chart.renderer.button('Reset Chart').destroy();
```

Neither throw errors but the button is not removed. How can I remove the button?

Comment: Have you tried to keep a rendered button in any variable and then call destroy() on it?

Comment: Yes. This works in a basic example (http://jsfiddle.net/wergeld/NxK39/15/) but it is not working in my use case where I am calling the destroy() in another function and not on a click event.

Answer (score 1):

I was over thinking it. Solution is to make the button object **scoped** correctly and then call:

```
custombutton.destroy();
```

This works flawlessly.